# Simple SQL function in WordPress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, function

I'm trying to create a function that can query data using SQL statement in WordPress. Here is my code.
All I get is NULL, what is wrong in my code?

```
function getCategory($getCat)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $query = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT category from wp_categoryname WHERE id=" .$getCat);
    echo $query->category;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that table exists: `wp_categoryname`. Are you using a plugin that creates table?

Comment: Wordpress doesn't have table named `wp_categoryname`, if you intend to query categories (not a custom made table) than you must query `wp_terms` table. (also tables `wp_terms_taxonomy` and `wp_terms_relationships` may be of use)

Comment: I have that wp_categoryname in my database. That is a custom made table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to fetch category name from ID

YOu can use to display the cat name.

```
 <?php echo get_cat_name($catID);?>
```

If you want to fetch all the details

```
  <?php get_category( $catID ) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query  from your custom table try :

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT category from wp_categoryname WHERE id=" .$getCat");
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hi I dont get it. Can you explain?

Comment: try the code as  new WP_Query( 'cat=2'); where 2 is a category id. print_r($query) and check the result

Comment: it produced something very long, that I dont really understand.

Comment: you want to query from your custom table?

Comment: yes,, the name of the table is wp_categoryname. I did tried to make a function so whatever value of ID is called it will query the data.eg,. getCat('value here');

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46982/discussion-between-nouphal-m-and-user2901740)